# Why some Russian interrogatives start with к- and others - with ч-?

Tags: этимология

Many Russian interrogatives start with к-:

кто?
кому?
куда?
кем?
как?
который?
где? (<кде?)
когда?

On the other hand, some interrogatives start with ч-. They seems to be case variants of "что?":

что?
чему?
чем?
чего?
о чём?

I suppose that all these interrogatives came from Proto-Indo-European "q<sup>u̯</sup>-", which also gave English wh- (as in what, who, when, which,...).

Yet I wonder why кто ("who") and "что"("what") got different initial consonant? Can it be explained solely by dissimilation?

Comment: Nice question. *Чей*, however, is not a form of *что*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Кто ("who") and "что"("what") have different initial consonants due to the so-called [*Slavic first palatalization*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavic_first_palatalization) which happened rather early, in the Proto=Slavic times.

> [Кто](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE#.D0.AD.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.8F) <  *Pr-Sl.* *kъ-to
>
> [Что](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE#.D0.AD.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.8F) <  *Pr-Sl.* *čь-to

During this palatalisation *k changed *k > *kʲ > *č before front vowels. *ь being a front vowel, *čь is the result of *ki undergoing the Slavic first palatalization, this *ki is a cognate of Greek `ti` ("what") and Latin `quid` ("what").